# How to make combobox lose focus automatically

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets and a home page where there are hyperlinks which lead to tabs in the workbook. I have a combobox dropdown on the home page. Selecting a value on the dropdown takes me to the corresponding tab.

When I navigate from the selected page back to the home page I see the combobox selection enabled. I need to manually override by pressing the Esc key.

Comment: Helps to show your existing code.

Comment: If you want only remove the focus, you can add a line like:     **Range("A1").Activate** that active the cell A1 before the other code (exit from this page).